# how to recognize which .apk is signed with debug key

Tags: android, debugging, apk

I'm working with Android application developers.
We need to recognize which APK package(.apk) is unsigned application package or signed application package.
Also we would like to distinguish which signed APK package is signed by private key or signed by debug key.
I know we could find these with Jarsigner tool.  But we can't figure out that way.  We have to find out with actual APK package(.apk file) which is generated by developers.

Here we found some clue.
When we uncompressed the signed APK package then we found a foler(META-INF) and three files(CERT.RSA, CERT, MANIFEST.MF).  When we open the CERT.RSA file with text editor, I could find the text, "Android Debug" in .apk was signed with the debug key.

So here is our question,

1. If I find the specific text, "Android Debug", then .apk is signed with the debug key.(correct or incorrect?)
2. If I uncompressed .apk and there is no CERT.RSA(*.RSA, I guess some case the file name is differnt) then .apk is unsigned. (correct or incorrect?)

Thank you for reading my question.
I'm looking forward to the answer.

Comment: I just have my build process create apk's with different filenames in release vs. debug.

Comment: To reply to an answer, you should use the "add comment" button below it. You can also edit your original post to add more information.

Comment: Thank you for giving me an imformation how to add comment. :)

Answer (score 1):

Both those things are correct (in general; you could have a key named Android Debug which was not the SDK debug key, but you'd have to be trying to defeat your purpose)

Comment: If you need to automate it you could write a script to decompress the APK and search for the aforementioned items.

Comment: You don't have to decompress the entire apk, you can just extract the signature file, potentially to pipe.

Comment: Thank you Chris Stratton.  We have to check with only .apk file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My English is not good. So I'd like to make it clear. these 2 things are correct below this comment?(sorry I can't put line breaker with this comment...)

Comment: 1. If .apk file was signed with the debug key by Eclipse, then I can absolutely find the text, "Android Debug" in CERT.RSA file.

Comment: 2. Unsigned .apk file have not CERT.RSA file with META-INF folder.